# Why is the hash of this file staying the same when I change its data?

Tags: node.js, file, hash, sha256, cryptojs

I'm trying to hash a file in JS with this piece of code:

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./file.txt', function(err,data){
     if(err) {
         console.error("Could not open file: %s", err);
         process.exit(1);
     }
         console.log("HASH: " + CryptoJS.SHA256(data));
});
```

No matter what I write into the .txt, the hash produced always is: `4ea5c508a6566e76240543f8feb06fd457777be39549c4016436afda65d2330e`

If I put some string data into `CryptoJS.SHA256("text_exemple")` the hash works correctly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback), if you don't pass an encoding, `data` is the raw buffer, not a string.

Comment: Try `fs.readFile('./file.txt', "utf8", function(err,data){...}`.  Although, I would think the buffer should *still* change the hash.

Comment: thanks @zero298, it worked!

Comment: @zero298 wanna post an answer so RAFAEL DA SILVA can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was curious *why* this wasn't working.  First, let's explain what is actually happening.  You don't include a file encoding type whenever you call `readFile`.  Per [`readFile` docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback):

> If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.

That's fine.  You would think that a buffer of a file would be just as hashable as the actual data in a file.  However, what is happening is that the crypto library doesn't account for receiving a Buffer, or rather, it only accounts for Strings.  You can see that in the source of the library here: [core.js:512](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/89ce2460ab1a10cdd0cefb686966414ce6a2ee6e/src/core.js#L518) where it does a `typeof data === 'string'` check.

Since `typeof a_buffer === "string"` evaluates to `false`, the hash is never updated.  Because of that, you get the same hash every time.

So, the solution is to just provide an encoding:

```
fs.readFile('./file.txt', "utf8", function(err,data){...}
```

or, do some operation to turn the Buffer into a String in such a way that you get the actual data, such as `data.toString("utf8")` where `data` is the Buffer from `readFile`.